# Появляется ошибка в Visual Studio Code при работе с Go

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

При написании кода на Go в VSCode, строка с package main подчеркивается красной волнистой линией. Если навести курсором на эту линию, то появляется вот такая надпись:

*gopls was not able to find modules in your workspace.
When outside of GOPATH, gopls needs to know which modules you are working on.
You can fix this by opening your workspace to a folder inside a Go module, or
by using a go.work file to specify multiple modules.
See the documentation for more information on setting up your workspace:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md.*

Пробовал почитать по этому поводу по ссылке предоставленной vscode, но ничего не понял, т.к. go я еще только только начал изучать.
Как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно создать модуль. Для этого в корневой папке проекта вам нужно вызвать команду `go mod init <имя_модуля>`

Например, у вас проект состоит из одного файла `/home/user/some/main.go`
Тогда в каталоге `/home/user/some/` нужно инициализировать модуль, например `go mod init example.org/first`

Имя модуля должно быть как URL, без пробелов и escape-последовательностей.

В результате в каталоге `/home/user/some/` появятся файлы `go.mod` и `go.sum`